# Не находит эммулятор

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке запустить свои тесты на эммуляторе, выбивает такая ошибка:

```
RUNNING EMULATOR emu_19_WXGA720 at : 2017-03-13 12:35:56 +0200
Restarting adb server
Emulator boot
PORT 5554 ready for emulator connection
Checking property dev.bootcomplete
[139992088864576]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
Restarting adb server
error: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

Пробовал убивать adb, переустановил эммулятор, перезагрузил ноут, clean project. Пожалуй всё что знал. Возможно кто то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Попробуйте перед тем, как запустить эмулятор, нажать на `Run 'app'`, чтобы инициализировать адб. Дальше включаете эмулятор и запускаете прилку.

Comment: @Соколов приложение запускается без проблем, эммулятор запускается. Но когда опять запускаю чтобы прогнать тесты, вылетает ошибка. У коллег по работе, таких проблем нет, хотя изменения одни и те же.

Comment: Возможно стоит установить qt library, не пробовали ?

Comment: @Morozov пробовал, установил qt5, проблема осталась.

Comment: Походу проблема с SDK, попробуйте поставить родную от студии, ну или переустановить старую.